# Oracle SQL left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am trying to take two queries and join the reults of query 2 (q2) to query 1 (q1) where usid match on both tables. 
I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00904: "Q2"."ENODEB_ID": invalid identifier.

```
SELECT 
  q1.Date_Range, q1.usid, q2.enodeb_id
FROM
(SELECT to_char(to_date(PERIODSTART,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM-DD') || '-' || to_char(to_date(PERIODEND,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM-DD') as Date_Range,
      usid FROM CQI_DASH.REGIONAL_LCQI_TOPOFFEND) q1
LEFT JOIN
(select usid, LISTAGG(ENODEB_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENODEB_ID)
FROM (
select usid,
       ENODEB_ID,
       row_number() over (partition by usid, ENODEB_ID order by usid) as rn
from AXIOM.NRS_LTE_ALU_CELLS
order by usid, ENODEB_ID)
WHERE rn = 1 
GROUP BY usid) q2
ON q1.usid = q2.usid;
```

Comment: Post DDL and sample data so that people can help.

Comment: Oracle is case sensitive.  It may have much to do with that string being in all caps some place, all lower in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your outer query you select `q2.enodeb_id`.

However, in the definition of `q2` you only select a LISTAGG, and you don't give it an alias. Did you mean to call it `enodeb_id`?

Comment: Yes I did. I missed the alias.

Answer (score 1):

The `LISTAGG(ENODEB_ID...` needs a column name alias. Is that what you want to be called as `ENODEB_ID` ?

If yes, try the following. Also if you format your SQL properly, it is easier to read and debug :)

```
SELECT 
  q1.Date_Range, q1.usid, q2.enodeb_id
FROM ( 
    SELECT to_char(to_date(PERIODSTART,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM-DD') || '-' || to_char(to_date(PERIODEND,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM-DD') as Date_Range,
        usid
    FROM CQI_DASH.REGIONAL_LCQI_TOPOFFEND) q1
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT usid, 
        LISTAGG(ENODEB_ID, ',') 
        WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ENODEB_ID ) AS ENODEB_ID
        FROM (
        SELECT usid,
           ENODEB_ID,
           row_number() over (partition by usid, ENODEB_ID order by usid) as rn
        FROM AXIOM.NRS_LTE_ALU_CELLS
        ORDER BY usid, ENODEB_ID
        )
WHERE rn = 1 
GROUP BY usid) q2
ON q1.usid = q2.usid;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `select`ed columns relating to `q2` are here:

```
select usid, LISTAGG(ENODEB_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENODEB_ID)
```

You don't have a column there named `ENODEB_ID`, thus the error. Perhaps you meant to alias the `listagg`?

```
select usid, LISTAGG(ENODEB_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ENODEB_ID) as ENODEB_ID
```